# Format object data to required format

Tags: javascript, object

back end want me to submit object like {"key":"value", "key2":"value2"} but sometimes user inputs {key: value, key1: value1}
or {key: "value", key2: "value2"}, it lacks of double quotation mark, so how can I convert all wrong format to goal object?
Note that when I get value from form, data will have double quotation mark like "{key:"value"}"

Comment: Well you can develop your own parser.... maybe a regular expression can do it if it is simple.

Comment: Is it always going to be `{"key":"value"} ` or can it be multiple keys and values?

Comment: @epascarello it has multiple keys and values, sorry I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

It seems the server is expecting a JSON format (application/json), then:

`{key: value, key1: value1}` is not a valid JSON

`{key: "value", key2: "value2"}` is not a valid JSON

If you are getting this values from some input field (HTML), then you can create a validation before sending the values to the server, and asking the users to correct the data. This validation can be easily developed with the JavaScript JSON Object, like that:

```
function isJSONValid(str) {
    let isValid = false;
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
        isValid = true;
    }
    catch (x) {}
    return isValid;
}
```

But if you really want to auto correct the input data, it may be kind complex because it's hard to know all kind of mistakes the user can do (if not impossible). You mentioned a simple JSON, but what if it has arrays, JSON inside JSONs, etc? For instance:

```
{ "field1": "{ field2: [ value1, "value2"] }", field3: value3 }
```

Note that in my example above, there are multiple mistakes.

If you want to auto correct just quotation mistakes for simple JSONs (not considering arrays, numeric values, JSON inside JSON, etc), the code below can help. But even so, it's possible to exist other mistakes. The validation is important!

```
function adjustQuotationMarks(str) {
    let newStr = str;
    newStr = newStr.replace(/"/g, '');
    newStr = newStr.replace(/{/g, '{ ');
    newStr = newStr.replace(/ ([^ ]+):/g, '"$1":');
    newStr = newStr.replace(/:([^:]+),/g, ':"$1",');
    newStr = newStr.replace(/:([^:]+)}/g, ':"$1"}');
    let newObj = {};
    JSON.parse(newStr, (key, value) => {
        if (value.trim) newObj[key] = value.trim();
    });

    return JSON.stringify(newObj);
}
```

Good luck.